# Quels accord et terminaison pour « Les patronnes se sont adjointτ des employés »

Tags: adjectifs, accord, pluriel, participe-passé

Dans la phrase « Les patronnes se sont adjoint*τ* des employés » où le tau *τ* représente la terminaison que je cherche à accorder, avec quoi s’accorde *adjointτ* ?

Devons-nous accorder avec *patronnes* et donc écrire *adjoint**es*** ou avec *employés* auquel cas on écrit *adjoint**s*** ?

Et pourquoi d’ailleurs, quelle en est la règle générale ?

Comment: https://wirtschaftssprachen.hslu.ch/francais/2013/06/17/autres-expressions-a-valeur-passive/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Les patronnes se sont **adjoint** des employés* car *se* est un complément d'objet indirect (ont adjoint des employés **à qui** ? **à** elles-mêmes). Il n'y a jamais d'accord du participe passé avec un COI et le COD est placé après le participe passé.

C'est la même règle qui conduit à ne pas accorder le participe passé dans :  *Elles se sont **lavé** les cheveux.*

À l'inverse, on écrit *Les employées se sont **adjointes** aux patronnes.* car ici, le COD est placé avant le participe passé (ont adjoint **qui** ? elles-mêmes).

Références : [conjugaison.com](https://www.conjugaison.com/grammaire/participe-pronominaux.html), [orthonet](http://orthonet.sdv.fr/php/rech_mot.php?mot=adjoint)

Comment: Mais pourquoi ne considère-t-on pas *s’adjoindre* comme un verbe pronominal, auquel cas avec l’auxiliaire *être* le participe passé s’accorderait avec le sujet ?
En fait, je trouve qu’il y’a de l’indécidabilité entre entre *adjoint* attribut du sujet du verbe *être* et *adjoint* participe passé. Comment peut-on trancher pour l’un ou l’autre et lever l’indécidabilité ?

Comment: @Fauve Ce sont les employées (COD)  qui sont adjointes. Comme *employées* est placé après le participe passé, on ne fait pas d'accord. À l'inverse, on écrit *Les employées se sont **adjointes** aux patronnes* ou *Les cheveux ont été **lavés** par elles.*